# Какой процесс проверяется в строке if (pid > 0)

Tags: linux, c

Создать N процессов, если один завершился - создать новый.
Есть код:

```
pid_t pid; 
pid_t pid1;
pid1 = fork();

for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if(pid1==pid)
    {
        pid = fork();
    }   
}

while(1)
{
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        wait(0);
        pid = fork();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой процесс проверяется в строке *if (pid > 0)*

Answer (score 2):

[fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) возвращает родительскому процессу идентификатор потомка, а потомку 0. Соответственно, в приведённом вами коде блок `if (pid > 0)` выполнится в родительском процессе, но не выполнится в порождённых.

Answer (score 1):

> какой процесс проверяется в строке if (pid > 0)

Смотрим *man 2 wait*:

> wait() This function waits for the first child to die.  The return
>   value is that of the wait(2) system call.

Это понятно? Т.е. если родитель наплодил кучу потомком и поставил *wait()* то он будет здесь ждать завершения **первого** дочернего процесса. Не того, кто был запущен первым, а того, кто первым завершился! Кто первый встал - того и тапки!

А вообще-то, то что Вы написали, выглядит довольно странно...

Answer (score 0):

Никакой не проверяется. Переменная `pid` в вашем коде не получает никакого осмысленного значения - это неинициализированная переменная.